# Как это решить в батнике?

Tags: bat

Задача: 
Создать командный файл при вызове, которого указать фамилию запускающего. Если запустил Иванов, то вывести строку: "Нет доступа", если запустил Петров, то вывести строку: "Не сегодня". Для всех других пользователей вывести информацию каталоге, из которого был запущен bat-файл. 
Почему это не работает?

```
@echo off
set a=Иванов
set b=Петров
set /P username="What is your name? "
if %username%==%a% echo Нет доступа
if %username%==%b% echo Не сегодня
pause
```

Comment: Какая версия OS?

Comment: Подумайте - что будет, если юзер просто нажмёт Enter. Кстати, а что в таком случае должно вывестись? PS. Вопрос не такой тривиальный, как кажется...

Answer (score 0):

(Уберите `@echo off`, запустите и вы сразу увидите, почему это не работает.)

Нужно задать правильную кодовую страницу. В Windows 10 достаточно добавить в начало файла

```
chcp 1251 >nul
```

Comment: Короче говоря лучше на английском напишу)) Оно и так не работает((